# WPF vb.net Populate Listview using Mysql Database

Tags: mysql, wpf, vb.net, listviewitem

```
                Try
                    strQuery = "SELECT * FROM thesis_db.std_records WHERE ProfIDNo=" & lstProfID.SelectedItem & " AND SubjectNo=" & SubjNo & " order by Student_LName"
                    MysqlCmd = New MySqlCommand(strQuery, MysqlConn)
                    MysqlDR = MysqlCmd.ExecuteReader
                    Dim arr(3) As String
                    Dim itm As ListViewItem
                    While MysqlDR.Read
                        arr(0) = MysqlDR.Item("Student_LName").ToString
                        arr(1) = MysqlDR.Item("Student_FName").ToString
                        arr(2) = MysqlDR.Item("Student_MI").ToString
                        arr(3) = MysqlDR.Item("Score").ToString
                        itm = New ListViewItem(arr)
                        lstStudent.Items.Add(itm)
                    End While
                    MysqlDR.Close()
                Catch ex As Exception
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
                End Try
```

The error is at line: lstStudent.Items.Add(itm). itm is underlined and its error says: Too many arguments to 'Public Sub New()'.

Comment: The error is most certainly one line before, at `itm = New ListViewItem(arr)`. Class ListViewItem does not have a constructor that takes an array of strings as parameter. Please read the online documentation of ListView and ListViewItem, especially about how to provide ListView content by binding its ItemsSource property to an ObservableCollection of data items.

Comment: A good start could be the [Data Templating Overview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742521.aspx) article on MSDN.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa335326%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

try something like this: 
change :

```
itm = New ListViewItem(arr)
lstStudent.Items.Add(itm)
```

with this :

```
For i=0 to 3
 Dim lvi As New ListViewItem(arr.ToString())
 Me.lstStudent.Items.Add(lvi)
Next



 'if you want subItem
    lvi.SubItems.Add(array2(i))
```

Comment: Has error in line: Dim lvi As New ListViewItem(arr().ToString()) arr is the underlined error which is: Number of indices is less than the number of dimensions of the indexed array. I inserted 3 in it. and same error as the first code: Too many arguments to 'Public Sub New()'.